# Are FPGAs used as Cubesat flight computers?

Tags: fpga

Are FPGAs used as Cubesat flight computers and are there benefits or drawbacks in using them?

Comment: Flagging question due to our rule of: "Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design."

Comment: Yes e.g https://www.brightascension.com/first-image-capture-for-seahawk/ mentions the use of FPGA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are FPGAs used as Cubesat flight computers and are there benefits or drawbacks in using them ?

Yes, they're used.

Their biggest disadvantage in a satellite is that they are essentially large chips that are very sensitive to ionizing radiation - which is a major problem in space, especially if your satellite isn't large enough to offer much shielding. Large surface + sensitive to radiation = high probability of erratic behaviour.

You'd want to use "rad-hard" (radiation hardened) components – but these get very expensive very quickly (because they're mostly used in spacecraft, transcontinental missiles, medical equipment, nuclear power plants – in short, places where you "just pay the price").

Since you're a beginner: As long as you're not 100% sure your problem can't be solved in software for a capable microcontroller, stay away from FPGAs. Hardware is hard, and FPGAs are configurable hardware and thus a whole new world, and FPGA design is really not trivial to get right the first try. Nothing you want to learn on >3·10⁴€ hardware in space.

Comment: Thank you! so in a nutshell FPGA is the last option there is.

Comment: @ivric not generally – there's a lot of problems that you *can't* solve in software, but you've given us no indication whatsoever that you've got one of these.

Comment: @ivric - No, an FPGA is NOT the last option.  It all comes down what you're trying to do in the FPGA (or software, or dedicated hardware); whether that can be done in software; what you mission's tolerance is to things like Total Incident Dose (TID), and Single Event Effects (SEEs).  Here's just one example - we're currently designing Xilinx Ultrascale FPGAs into a new application for space,

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are. I was talking to a Micronova about customizing one of their FPGA modules and they mentioned a customer used one in their cubesat

Comment: Haven't you just exposed some NDA info?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know if I did. I didn't sign anything. Maybe they did? I just kind of assumed it was a student project.

Comment: Okay, I guess you didn't sign anything :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Actually, I went back and looked at the e-mail. It never said it was used in a cubesat. It just said a satellite, and since I assumed it was a student project my mind filled in the gaps with a cubesat.